# How do I group an array of objects by a singular array property embedded within a property of that array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that comes in from an api. The data is in this format:

```
[
    {
        "__typename": "directus_fields",
        "field": "heading",
        "type": "string",
        "schema": {
            "__typename": "directus_fields_schema",
            "max_length": 255,
            "is_unique": false,
            "is_nullable": true
        },
        "meta": {
            "__typename": "directus_fields_meta",
            "group": "hero",
            "validation_message": null,
            "id": 37,
            "required": false,
            "validation": null,
            "interface": "input",
            "hidden": false
        }
    },
    {
        "__typename": "directus_fields",
        "field": "introduction",
        "type": "text",
        "schema": {
            "__typename": "directus_fields_schema",
            "max_length": null,
            "is_unique": false,
            "is_nullable": true
        },
        "meta": {
            "__typename": "directus_fields_meta",
            "group": "about_us",
            "validation_message": null,
            "id": 38,
            "required": false,
            "validation": null,
            "interface": "input-rich-text-html",
            "hidden": false
        }
    },
    {
        "__typename": "directus_fields",
        "field": "campaign_title",
        "type": "string",
        "schema": {
            "__typename": "directus_fields_schema",
            "max_length": 255,
            "is_unique": false,
            "is_nullable": true
        },
        "meta": {
            "__typename": "directus_fields_meta",
            "group": "campaign",
            "validation_message": null,
            "id": 41,
            "required": false,
            "validation": null,
            "interface": "input",
            "hidden": false
        }
    },
    {
        "__typename": "directus_fields",
        "field": "campaign_duration",
        "type": "string",
        "schema": {
            "__typename": "directus_fields_schema",
            "max_length": 255,
            "is_unique": false,
            "is_nullable": true
        },
        "meta": {
            "__typename": "directus_fields_meta",
            "group": "campaign",
            "validation_message": null,
            "id": 42,
            "required": false,
            "validation": null,
            "interface": "input",
            "hidden": false
        }
    },
    {
        "__typename": "directus_fields",
        "field": "campaign_text",
        "type": "text",
        "schema": {
            "__typename": "directus_fields_schema",
            "max_length": null,
            "is_unique": false,
            "is_nullable": true
        },
        "meta": {
            "__typename": "directus_fields_meta",
            "group": "campaign",
            "validation_message": null,
            "id": 43,
            "required": false,
            "validation": null,
            "interface": "input-rich-text-html",
            "hidden": false
        }
    },
    {
        "__typename": "directus_fields",
        "field": "campaign_image",
        "type": "uuid",
        "schema": {
            "__typename": "directus_fields_schema",
            "max_length": 36,
            "is_unique": false,
            "is_nullable": true
        },
        "meta": {
            "__typename": "directus_fields_meta",
            "group": "campaign",
            "validation_message": null,
            "id": 44,
            "required": false,
            "validation": null,
            "interface": "file-image",
            "hidden": false
        }
    },
    {
        "__typename": "directus_fields",
        "field": "philosophy_title",
        "type": "string",
        "schema": {
            "__typename": "directus_fields_schema",
            "max_length": 255,
            "is_unique": false,
            "is_nullable": true
        },
        "meta": {
            "__typename": "directus_fields_meta",
            "group": "philosophy",
            "validation_message": null,
            "id": 45,
            "required": false,
            "validation": null,
            "interface": "input",
            "hidden": false
        }
    },
    {
        "__typename": "directus_fields",
        "field": "philosophy_text",
        "type": "text",
        "schema": {
            "__typename": "directus_fields_schema",
            "max_length": null,
            "is_unique": false,
            "is_nullable": true
        },
        "meta": {
            "__typename": "directus_fields_meta",
            "group": "philosophy",
            "validation_message": null,
            "id": 46,
            "required": false,
            "validation": null,
            "interface": "input-rich-text-html",
            "hidden": false
        }
    },
    {
        "__typename": "directus_fields",
        "field": "title",
        "type": "string",
        "schema": {
            "__typename": "directus_fields_schema",
            "max_length": 255,
            "is_unique": false,
            "is_nullable": true
        },
        "meta": {
            "__typename": "directus_fields_meta",
            "group": "about_us",
            "validation_message": null,
            "id": 52,
            "required": false,
            "validation": null,
            "interface": "input",
            "hidden": false
        }
    },
    {
        "__typename": "directus_fields",
        "field": "hero_text",
        "type": "text",
        "schema": {
            "__typename": "directus_fields_schema",
            "max_length": null,
            "is_unique": false,
            "is_nullable": true
        },
        "meta": {
            "__typename": "directus_fields_meta",
            "group": "hero",
            "validation_message": null,
            "id": 164,
            "required": false,
            "validation": null,
            "interface": "input-rich-text-html",
            "hidden": false
        }
    }
]
```

I would like to group the data in the array by the meta group name. All meta group names that are similar should be in a new array object.

I tried this but I couldnt get it to work

```
const tree = [];
    const children = {};
    data.forEach((item) => {
        const newItem = { ...item } as ParsedMenuItem;
        const { id: newItem?.meta?.group, parentId: parentId = 0 } = newItem;
        children[id] = children[id] || [];
        newItem.childMenu = children[id];
        parentId
            ? (children[parentId] = children[parentId] || []).push(newItem)
            : tree.push(newItem);
    });
    return tree;
```

I just want all similar meta group name to be under one object. I have no idea on how to go about this due to the nested structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group your data by `meta.group` using `Array.reduce()`. Here is an example:

```js
result = data.reduce((a, i) => {
  a[i.meta.group] = a[i.meta.group] || [];
  a[i.meta.group].push(i);
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script>
  let data = [{
      "__typename": "directus_fields",
      "field": "heading",
      "type": "string",
      "schema": {
        "__typename": "directus_fields_schema",
        "max_length": 255,
        "is_unique": false,
        "is_nullable": true
      },
      "meta": {
        "__typename": "directus_fields_meta",
        "group": "hero",
        "validation_message": null,
        "id": 37,
        "required": false,
        "validation": null,
        "interface": "input",
        "hidden": false
      }
    },
    {
      "__typename": "directus_fields",
      "field": "introduction",
      "type": "text",
      "schema": {
        "__typename": "directus_fields_schema",
        "max_length": null,
        "is_unique": false,
        "is_nullable": true
      },
      "meta": {
        "__typename": "directus_fields_meta",
        "group": "about_us",
        "validation_message": null,
        "id": 38,
        "required": false,
        "validation": null,
        "interface": "input-rich-text-html",
        "hidden": false
      }
    },
    {
      "__typename": "directus_fields",
      "field": "campaign_title",
      "type": "string",
      "schema": {
        "__typename": "directus_fields_schema",
        "max_length": 255,
        "is_unique": false,
        "is_nullable": true
      },
      "meta": {
        "__typename": "directus_fields_meta",
        "group": "campaign",
        "validation_message": null,
        "id": 41,
        "required": false,
        "validation": null,
        "interface": "input",
        "hidden": false
      }
    },
    {
      "__typename": "directus_fields",
      "field": "campaign_duration",
      "type": "string",
      "schema": {
        "__typename": "directus_fields_schema",
        "max_length": 255,
        "is_unique": false,
        "is_nullable": true
      },
      "meta": {
        "__typename": "directus_fields_meta",
        "group": "campaign",
        "validation_message": null,
        "id": 42,
        "required": false,
        "validation": null,
        "interface": "input",
        "hidden": false
      }
    },
    {
      "__typename": "directus_fields",
      "field": "campaign_text",
      "type": "text",
      "schema": {
        "__typename": "directus_fields_schema",
        "max_length": null,
        "is_unique": false,
        "is_nullable": true
      },
      "meta": {
        "__typename": "directus_fields_meta",
        "group": "campaign",
        "validation_message": null,
        "id": 43,
        "required": false,
        "validation": null,
        "interface": "input-rich-text-html",
        "hidden": false
      }
    },
    {
      "__typename": "directus_fields",
      "field": "campaign_image",
      "type": "uuid",
      "schema": {
        "__typename": "directus_fields_schema",
        "max_length": 36,
        "is_unique": false,
        "is_nullable": true
      },
      "meta": {
        "__typename": "directus_fields_meta",
        "group": "campaign",
        "validation_message": null,
        "id": 44,
        "required": false,
        "validation": null,
        "interface": "file-image",
        "hidden": false
      }
    },
    {
      "__typename": "directus_fields",
      "field": "philosophy_title",
      "type": "string",
      "schema": {
        "__typename": "directus_fields_schema",
        "max_length": 255,
        "is_unique": false,
        "is_nullable": true
      },
      "meta": {
        "__typename": "directus_fields_meta",
        "group": "philosophy",
        "validation_message": null,
        "id": 45,
        "required": false,
        "validation": null,
        "interface": "input",
        "hidden": false
      }
    },
    {
      "__typename": "directus_fields",
      "field": "philosophy_text",
      "type": "text",
      "schema": {
        "__typename": "directus_fields_schema",
        "max_length": null,
        "is_unique": false,
        "is_nullable": true
      },
      "meta": {
        "__typename": "directus_fields_meta",
        "group": "philosophy",
        "validation_message": null,
        "id": 46,
        "required": false,
        "validation": null,
        "interface": "input-rich-text-html",
        "hidden": false
      }
    },
    {
      "__typename": "directus_fields",
      "field": "title",
      "type": "string",
      "schema": {
        "__typename": "directus_fields_schema",
        "max_length": 255,
        "is_unique": false,
        "is_nullable": true
      },
      "meta": {
        "__typename": "directus_fields_meta",
        "group": "about_us",
        "validation_message": null,
        "id": 52,
        "required": false,
        "validation": null,
        "interface": "input",
        "hidden": false
      }
    },
    {
      "__typename": "directus_fields",
      "field": "hero_text",
      "type": "text",
      "schema": {
        "__typename": "directus_fields_schema",
        "max_length": null,
        "is_unique": false,
        "is_nullable": true
      },
      "meta": {
        "__typename": "directus_fields_meta",
        "group": "hero",
        "validation_message": null,
        "id": 164,
        "required": false,
        "validation": null,
        "interface": "input-rich-text-html",
        "hidden": false
      }
    }
  ]
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this.